# Cannot decommission cockroachdb node

Tags: cockroachdb, cockroachcloud

Inside Kubernetes, after scale node, cannot decommission

```
{"level":"warn","ts":1665138574.1910405,"logger":"controller.CrdbCluster","msg":"scaling down stateful set","CrdbCluster":"cockroach-cluster-stage/cockroachdb","ReconcileId":"kF7Vns39vPGnqXncUhmWnX","have":5,"want":4}
{"level":"error","ts":1665138574.8271742,"logger":"controller.CrdbCluster","msg":"decommission failed","CrdbCluster":"cockroach-cluster-stage/cockroachdb","ReconcileId":"kF7Vns39vPGnqXncUhmWnX","error":"failed to stream execution results back: command terminated with exit code 1","errorVerbose":"failed to stream execution results back: command terminated with exit code 1\n(1) attached stack trace\n  -- stack trace:\n  | github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-operator/pkg/scale.CockroachExecutor.Exec\n  | \tpkg/scale/executor.go:57\n  | github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-operator/pkg/scale.(*CockroachNodeDrainer).findNodeID\n  | \tpkg/scale/drainer.go:242\n  | github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-operator/pkg/scale.(*CockroachNodeDrainer).Decommission\n  | \tpkg/scale/drainer.go:79\n  | github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-operator/pkg/scale.(*Scaler).EnsureScale\n  | \tpkg/scale/scale.go:91\n  | github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-operator/pkg/actor.decommission.Act\n  | \tpkg/actor/decommission.go:143\n  | github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-operator/pkg/controller.(*ClusterReconciler).Reconcile\n  | \tpkg/controller/cluster_controller.go:153\n  | sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).reconcileHandler\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_sigs_controller_runtime/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:297\n  | sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).processNextWorkItem\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_sigs_controller_runtime/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:252\n  | sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).Start.func1.2\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_sigs_controller_runtime/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:215\n  | k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntilWithContext.func1\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:185\n  | k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.BackoffUntil.func1\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:155\n  | k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.BackoffUntil\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:156\n  | k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntil\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:133\n  | k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntilWithContext\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:185\n  | k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.UntilWithContext\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:99\n  | runtime.goexit\n  | \tsrc/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581\nWraps: (2) failed to stream execution results back\nWraps: (3) command terminated with exit code 1\nError types: (1) *withstack.withStack (2) *errutil.withPrefix (3) exec.CodeExitError","stacktrace":"github.com/go-logr/zapr.(*zapLogger).Error\n\texternal/com_github_go_logr_zapr/zapr.go:132\ngithub.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-operator/pkg/actor.decommission.Act\n\tpkg/actor/decommission.go:145\ngithub.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-operator/pkg/controller.(*ClusterReconciler).Reconcile\n\tpkg/controller/cluster_controller.go:153\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).reconcileHandler\n\texternal/io_k8s_sigs_controller_runtime/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:297\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).processNextWorkItem\n\texternal/io_k8s_sigs_controller_runtime/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:252\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).Start.func1.2\n\texternal/io_k8s_sigs_controller_runtime/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:215\nk8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntilWithContext.func1\n\texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:185\nk8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.BackoffUntil.func1\n\texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:155\nk8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.BackoffUntil\n\texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:156\nk8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntil\n\texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:133\nk8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntilWithContext\n\texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:185\nk8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.UntilWithContext\n\texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:99"}
{"level":"info","ts":1665138574.8283174,"logger":"controller.CrdbCluster","msg":"Error on action","CrdbCluster":"cockroach-cluster-stage/cockroachdb","ReconcileId":"kF7Vns39vPGnqXncUhmWnX","Action":"Decommission","err":"failed to stream execution results back: command terminated with exit code 1"}
{"level":"error","ts":1665138574.8283627,"logger":"controller.CrdbCluster","msg":"action failed","CrdbCluster":"cockroach-cluster-stage/cockroachdb","ReconcileId":"kF7Vns39vPGnqXncUhmWnX","error":"failed to stream execution results back: command terminated with exit code 1","errorVerbose":"failed to stream execution results back: command terminated with exit code 1\n(1) attached stack trace\n  -- stack trace:\n  | github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-operator/pkg/scale.CockroachExecutor.Exec\n  | \tpkg/scale/executor.go:57\n  | github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-operator/pkg/scale.(*CockroachNodeDrainer).findNodeID\n  | \tpkg/scale/drainer.go:242\n  | github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-operator/pkg/scale.(*CockroachNodeDrainer).Decommission\n  | \tpkg/scale/drainer.go:79\n  | github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-operator/pkg/scale.(*Scaler).EnsureScale\n  | \tpkg/scale/scale.go:91\n  | github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-operator/pkg/actor.decommission.Act\n  | \tpkg/actor/decommission.go:143\n  | github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-operator/pkg/controller.(*ClusterReconciler).Reconcile\n  | \tpkg/controller/cluster_controller.go:153\n  | sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).reconcileHandler\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_sigs_controller_runtime/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:297\n  | sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).processNextWorkItem\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_sigs_controller_runtime/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:252\n  | sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).Start.func1.2\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_sigs_controller_runtime/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:215\n  | k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntilWithContext.func1\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:185\n  | k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.BackoffUntil.func1\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:155\n  | k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.BackoffUntil\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:156\n  | k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntil\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:133\n  | k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntilWithContext\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:185\n  | k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.UntilWithContext\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:99\n  | runtime.goexit\n  | \tsrc/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581\nWraps: (2) failed to stream execution results back\nWraps: (3) command terminated with exit code 1\nError types: (1) *withstack.withStack (2) *errutil.withPrefix (3) exec.CodeExitError","stacktrace":"github.com/go-logr/zapr.(*zapLogger).Error\n\texternal/com_github_go_logr_zapr/zapr.go:132\ngithub.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-operator/pkg/controller.(*ClusterReconciler).Reconcile\n\tpkg/controller/cluster_controller.go:185\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).reconcileHandler\n\texternal/io_k8s_sigs_controller_runtime/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:297\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).processNextWorkItem\n\texternal/io_k8s_sigs_controller_runtime/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:252\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).Start.func1.2\n\texternal/io_k8s_sigs_controller_runtime/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:215\nk8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntilWithContext.func1\n\texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:185\nk8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.BackoffUntil.func1\n\texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:155\nk8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.BackoffUntil\n\texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:156\nk8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntil\n\texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:133\nk8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntilWithContext\n\texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:185\nk8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.UntilWithContext\n\texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:99"}
{"level":"error","ts":1665138574.836441,"logger":"controller-runtime.manager.controller.crdbcluster","msg":"Reconciler error","reconciler group":"crdb.cockroachlabs.com","reconciler kind":"CrdbCluster","name":"cockroachdb","namespace":"cockroach-cluster-stage","error":"failed to stream execution results back: command terminated with exit code 1","errorVerbose":"failed to stream execution results back: command terminated with exit code 1\n(1) attached stack trace\n  -- stack trace:\n  | github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-operator/pkg/scale.CockroachExecutor.Exec\n  | \tpkg/scale/executor.go:57\n  | github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-operator/pkg/scale.(*CockroachNodeDrainer).findNodeID\n  | \tpkg/scale/drainer.go:242\n  | github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-operator/pkg/scale.(*CockroachNodeDrainer).Decommission\n  | \tpkg/scale/drainer.go:79\n  | github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-operator/pkg/scale.(*Scaler).EnsureScale\n  | \tpkg/scale/scale.go:91\n  | github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-operator/pkg/actor.decommission.Act\n  | \tpkg/actor/decommission.go:143\n  | github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-operator/pkg/controller.(*ClusterReconciler).Reconcile\n  | \tpkg/controller/cluster_controller.go:153\n  | sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).reconcileHandler\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_sigs_controller_runtime/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:297\n  | sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).processNextWorkItem\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_sigs_controller_runtime/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:252\n  | sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).Start.func1.2\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_sigs_controller_runtime/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:215\n  | k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntilWithContext.func1\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:185\n  | k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.BackoffUntil.func1\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:155\n  | k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.BackoffUntil\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:156\n  | k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntil\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:133\n  | k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntilWithContext\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:185\n  | k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.UntilWithContext\n  | \texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:99\n  | runtime.goexit\n  | \tsrc/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581\nWraps: (2) failed to stream execution results back\nWraps: (3) command terminated with exit code 1\nError types: (1) *withstack.withStack (2) *errutil.withPrefix (3) exec.CodeExitError","stacktrace":"github.com/go-logr/zapr.(*zapLogger).Error\n\texternal/com_github_go_logr_zapr/zapr.go:132\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).reconcileHandler\n\texternal/io_k8s_sigs_controller_runtime/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:301\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).processNextWorkItem\n\texternal/io_k8s_sigs_controller_runtime/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:252\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).Start.func1.2\n\texternal/io_k8s_sigs_controller_runtime/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:215\nk8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntilWithContext.func1\n\texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:185\nk8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.BackoffUntil.func1\n\texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:155\nk8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.BackoffUntil\n\texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:156\nk8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntil\n\texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:133\nk8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntilWithContext\n\texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:185\nk8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.UntilWithContext\n\texternal/io_k8s_apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:99"}
{"level":"info","ts":1665138584.3979504,"logger":"controller.CrdbCluster","msg":"reconciling CockroachDB cluster","CrdbCluster":"cockroach-cluster-stage/cockroachdb","ReconcileId":"URAajRJhYWotEB4tQs6hRm"}
{"level":"info","ts":1665138584.3980412,"logger":"webhooks","msg":"default","name":"cockroachdb"}
{"level":"info","ts":1665138584.4027824,"logger":"controller.CrdbCluster","msg":"Running action with name: Decommission","CrdbCluster":"cockroach-cluster-stage/cockroachdb","ReconcileId":"URAajRJhYWotEB4tQs6hRm"}
{"level":"warn","ts":1665138584.4028075,"logger":"controller.CrdbCluster","msg":"check decommission opportunities","CrdbCluster":"cockroach-cluster-stage/cockroachdb","ReconcileId":"URAajRJhYWotEB4tQs6hRm"}
{"level":"info","ts":1665138584.4028518,"logger":"controller.CrdbCluster","msg":"replicas decommissioning","CrdbCluster":"cockroach-cluster-stage/cockroachdb","ReconcileId":"URAajRJhYWotEB4tQs6hRm","status.CurrentReplicas":5,"expected":4}
{"level":"warn","ts":1665138584.4028952,"logger":"controller.CrdbCluster","msg":"operator is running inside of kubernetes, connecting to service for db connection","CrdbCluster":"cockroach-cluster-stage/cockroachdb","ReconcileId":"URAajRJhYWotEB4tQs6hRm"}
```

Comment: That might be a timeout waiting for the node to shut down gracefully, in which case it's possible the decommission actually succeeded even though it was marked as failed.

Comment: I know but cannot find any flag for adding timeot.As a result, cannot decommission :/

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug and should be fixed by this [PR](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-operator/pull/935)